# template variadic function constraint

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

As following codes I got "the associated constraints are not satisfied" compiler (MVC19) error.  But without variadic parameters it works fine.

Thank you in advance for your support.

```
template<
    typename    _ChFunction,
    typename... _ChArguments>
concept ChProcessSignalFunctionReturnVoid = requires (
    _ChFunction         ChFunction,
    _ChArguments&&...   ChArguments)
{
    ChFunction(ChArguments...);
    //ChFunction((ChArguments + ...)); also tried
};

template <
    ChProcessSignalFunctionReturnVoid   _ChFunction,
    typename...                         _ChParameters>
constexpr void  ChExecute(
    _ChFunction         ChFunction,
    _ChParameters&&...  ChParameters)
{
}


int main()
{
    ChExecute(
        [](int a, int   b)->void
        {
        },
        5,
        10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not passing any template arguments to `ChProcessSignalFunctionReturnVoid`. `ConceptName T` is equivalent to `typename T` `requires ConceptName<T>`, so your parameter pack is empty. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Also note that identifiers starting with `_[A-Z]` are reserved, you shouldn't use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass parameter types to `ChProcessSignalFunctionReturnVoid` concept to check if `_ChFunction` can be invoked with these arguments

```
template <
    typename...                         _ChParameters,
    ChProcessSignalFunctionReturnVoid<_ChParameters...>   _ChFunction>
constexpr void  ChExecute(
    _ChFunction         ChFunction,
    _ChParameters&&...  ChParameters)
{
}
```

Comment: You are amazing and thank you. How did I miss it? This must be professional blindness.